# php session issue in remove value from Cart Sessin Array

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii

I am using Yii Framework and am unable to remove a value from a session. When I call the function using ajax, I get this error in console

> Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect

Any suggestion will be helpful thanks in advance . Below is my code

```
public function actiondeleteproductajax() {
    $session = Yii::app()->session;
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : "";
    $key = array_search($id, $session['cart_items']);
    if ($key !== false) {
        unset($session['cart_items'][$key]);
        echo 'success';
    }
}
```

i want to remove index of array because value containt similar ids of products added more than one time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cartItems = Yii::app()->session['cart_items'];
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : "";
$key = array_search($id, $cartItems);
if ($key !== false) {
    unset($cartItems[$key]);
    echo 'success';
}
Yii::app()->session['cart_items'] = $cartItems;
```

You cannot directly modify the `session` item, it is internally handled by yii with getters and setters, so `unset()` will have no effect, hence the warning.
You can however unset an item in your copy `$cartItems` and assign the remaining array back to the `session object`.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the class in question is using [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) to give you the value

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
```

If you look at the class itself, there should be a `__get` function and `$session` is likely `private` or `protected`. When you access the `$session` variable it's returning a **copy**. That's why it's telling you that your `unset` isn't having any effect.